# How to insert LUI Icon "arrow-down" with CSS

Tags: html, css, qliksense

I'm trying to insert LUI (Leonardi UI) library icons with CSS into our web app (QlikSense).

It works perfectly fine with icons with one "word" such as  "play":

```
.source-sans-pro .qv-collapsed-listbox .title-wrapper::after {
    font-family: "LUI icons" !important;
    content: "play";
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

However, when trying to add icons with two "words" such as "arrow-down", it wont work anymore:

```
.source-sans-pro .qv-collapsed-listbox .title-wrapper::after {
    font-family: "LUI icons" !important;
    content: "arrow-down";
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Anyone an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and replace the `-` with an `_` (underscore) character, e.g. `content: "arrow_down";`